# SPARQL SERVICE with protected endpoint

Tags: tomcat, sparql, blazegraph, federated-queries

I need to use a protected endpoint to formulate a federated query in SPARQL like:

```
select ?s ?p ?o
{
 SERVICE <https://mysqparlendpoint/sparql/> {
   select ?s ?p ?o {
      ?s ?p ?o
   } limit 10
 }
}
```

Unfortunately in the SERVICE spec there is no hint how to do that. https://mysqparlendpoint/sparql is supposed to be a blazegraph on a tomcat, whose access is Basic secured.

How can I formulate this SPARQL query accessing the endpoint using credentials to open it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: 1. Is `<https://user:rpassword@mysparqlendpoint/sparql>` not working? 2. Which triplestore are you using?

Comment: If your local endpoint is Blazegraph too, then see https://jira.blazegraph.com/browse/BLZG-1966

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, it is a blazegraph. The issue is from 2016 ... and, yes using "https://demo:demo@ch.semweb.ch:10000/S2Mapi/thesaurus/ASSEMBLY/sparql/q=select%20*%20%7B%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%7D%20limit%203&format=xml" seems to deliver results. However: Inside a blazegraph console, a federated query using https://demo:demo@ch.semweb.ch:10000/S2Mapi/thesaurus/ASSEMBLY/sparql/ as a SPARQL Endpoint URL delivers again a 401 ...

Comment: The problem was issuing that query inside a Blazegraph console. E.G. in http://factforge.net/sparql (GraphDB) it runs smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

SPARQL 1.1 Federation does not specify any way to authenticate.

Vendor-specific solutions:

- Blazegraph allows the usual notation `user:password@server:port` as explained above
- Ontotext GraphDB has [internal federation](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/internal-federation.html) that works across two password-protected repos on the same GraphDB instance

I've posted a SPARQL 1.2 issue: https://github.com/w3c/sparql-12/issues/117